# How to get the iPod Nano 5th gen battery health

Tags: battery, ipod-nano

Is there any way I can get the battery health of an iPod, specifically a 5th gen Nano?
I've done a little bit of googling and I don't think there is a way, but I though I could give it a try here.

I would like to buy a used iPod Nano (5th gen), but I am worried that the battery might not last very long, so I was wondering if there is any way I could check that (other than playing a song over and over again).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple have software at the Genius Bars which can diagnose faults, read the current voltage, and assess the health of devices but I've never been able to find a copy before.

There is a diagnostic mode for iPods which you can access by resetting the device with Menu+Select and then upon seeing the Apple logo, press Rewind+Select. There are many tests on there including some battery ones within the Power section, however I doubt this will tell you much without a lot of research.

Basically, no, there's no easy way to test the battery other than playing a song over and over as you've stated. Perhaps you could get a quick written agreement with the seller that you'd expect the battery to be at least 80% as good as the expected battery life or something along those lines, and if not they will refund you?